# Selecting a non-visible item in the dropdown for a GXT ComboBox

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gxt

I am trying to test an application written using GWT 2.3.0 and GXT 2.2.5 with the Selenium 2.25 WebDriver on Java.

In the application, I have a ComboBox with a large number of options, so many that the list has a scrollbar. I need to select an item that is not visible in the list.

I run the test using the following code:

```java
//xpath for combobox trigger
String xpathExpression = "//div[starts-with(@id,'combobox ID']/descendant::img[contains(@class,'x-form-trigger-arrow')]";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathExpression)).click();

//xpath for combobox list item
xpathExpression = "//div[contains(@class,'x-combo-list-item']/descendant::div[text()='item text']";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathExpression)).click();
```

where *comboBoxID* is the ID prefix I use to identify the ComboBox and *item text* is the text displayed in the drop-down list for the item.

If the item is visible on the page, the test runs fine. If the item is too far down on the list to be seen, I get an *ElementNotVisibleException*.

Is there any way for me to select the non-visible item?

Answer (score 0):

Since element is not visible you cannot get a handle on it using Selenium. So one solution would be to first scroll the drop down to get to that element then do the selection.

The `divs` corresponding to those select values are not visible they are rendered in the DOM. Otherwise it will be rendered on the fly when you scroll. So you can execute a javascript code and set the focus (if it's already rendered not visible) to the element which you want to get or scroll the drop down (if not rendered) and select using your selectors. For example

```
WebDriver driver = /*driver you created*/;
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
   JavascriptExecutor jsExec = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
   //you need to use the correct javascript here to do the scrolling or get the focus ex:
   String js = "document.getElementById("elementID").scrollIntoView()";
   jsExec.executeScript(js);
}
```

Then you will probably have to run above code under expected condition like `visibilityOfElementLocated`

Comment: I'll give that a try, although my JavaScript experience is minimal.

This sounds like something Selenium would include in their library.